# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError starting Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse Oxygen on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 system. When I run the executable it fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "logback configurator timer" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/util/StatusPrinter
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter cannot be found by org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration_1.8.0.20160921-2002
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 6 more
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

What is going on here? Do I need to install additional libraries to run Eclipse Oxygen?

Comment: Did you tried `eclipse -clean`?

Comment: @howlger I just tried it, I get the exact same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug or a particular problem with release M2 of Eclipse Oxygen. I Just installed [release a.1](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) and it starts up correctly.